# ajax get with nested json - nested properties doesn't bind in controller

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, ajax, json

When I send json with nested properties via **ajax GET**, then in controller action nestes object properties (Searching) does not bind. 
On the other hand when I use **Ajax POST** then everything is bind correctly.

What do I do wrong in the AJAX GET example?

Here is my code

```
var queryData = {
    startDate : 1361577600000,
    stopDate : 1388361600000,
    sortColumn : "videoviews",
    mediaId : "",
    startIndex : startIndex,
    count : count,
    search : searchStr,
    searching: {
        search1 : "jjj",
        search2 : "sss",
        search3 : "a"
    }
};
```

client1 (on server Searching is created but does not bind):

```
 $.ajax({
    url: '/Query/TotalBrowsersDetails',
    type: 'GET',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    data: queryData,
    success: function (data, status, xhr) {
        console.log('ajax success');
    }
});
```

server1:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult TotalBrowsersDetails(QueryRequest queryRequest)
{
}
```

client2 (works ok):

```
 $.ajax({
    url: '/Query/TotalBrowsersDetails',
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    data: JSON.stringify(queryData),
    success: function (data, status, xhr) {
        console.log('ajax success ');
    }
});
```

server2:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult TotalBrowsersDetails(QueryRequest queryRequest)
{
}
```

and the model

```
  public class QueryRequest
        {
            public string MediaId { get; set; }
            public string SortColumn { get; set; }
            public string Search { get; set; }
            public int StartIndex { get; set; }
            public int Count { get; set; }
            public long StartDate { get; set; }
            public long StopDate { get; set; }

            public SearchExtended Searching { get; set; }
        }

        public class SearchExtended
        {
            public string Search1 { get; set; }
            public string Search2 { get; set; }
            public string Search3 { get; set; }
        }
    }
```

**NOTE**: when i use

```
data: JSON.stringify(queryData)
```

in the GET then nothing binds.

Comment: try `data: $.param(queryData)`

Comment: Both of your methods are in the same class and have the same signature, are you changing **Get** to **Post** and hitting debug again to test?  I've had issues with this recently, where whenever I make a change like this I need to insure IIS Express has closed and Rebuild to properly see my changes, might be worth a shot!

Comment: @AntoJSubash after using $.param nothing changes (still binds only top level properties)

Comment: @JMK YES. But now I split methods to two different, iisreset and still the same. Aplication is deployed to IIS.

Comment: @AntoJSubash $.param(queryData) return this
"startDate=1387324800000&stopDate=1389916800000&sortColumn=videoviews&mediaId=&startIndex=0&count=5&search=browsername&searching%5Bsearch1%5D=jjj&searching%5Bsearch2%5D=sss&searching%5Bsearch3%5D=a"